# How to convert ascii-8bit file data to readable string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, character-encoding

I'm trying to parse the contents of a CSV file (saved on Windows Excel then uploaded to dropbox) from my dropbox via the [Dropbox Core api](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/ruby).

I create a rake task (part of a Rails app) with the following code and it creates a magnum-opus.csv file on my local hard drive that has the original text in the Excel file.  The encoding of contents is ASCII-8BIT by calling contents.encoding

```
contents, metadata = client.get_file_and_metadata('/magnum-opus.csv')
open('magnum-opus.csv', 'w') {|f| f.puts contents }
```

Instead of creating a local file, I'd like to convert the binary data in "contents" to readable text on the fly and parse through it.  I don't want to save it anywhere and then have to open it.

How do I go about doing that?

If do

```
p contents
```

I end up getting some type of unreadable data format ...  \x00e\x00d\x00u

1)  How do I convert this into a string I can parse through with Ruby?
2)  The other thing I'm wondering - if do:

```
puts contents
```

The original text in the CSV file that is human readable is outputed to STDOUT.  What is puts doing?

I tried:

```
calling CSV.parse on contents.encode( "UTF-8", "binary", :invalid => :replace, :undef => :replace, :replace => '') but end up getting an error such as
```

*CSV::MalformedCSVError: Unquoted fields do not allow \r or \n*

Comment: What? 8-bit ASCII data is just about as readable a string as you can get, second only to 7-bit ASCII.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart - can you point me in the right direction of converting the 8-bit ASCII into a readable format?  I get back something like "\x000\x0c...".

Comment: All those zero bytes would suggest that your CSV file is UTF-16 encoded, perhaps you should try changing the encoding to UTF-8 when you read it.

Comment: mu is too short, I tried that and I end up getting an error when I read it....It seems like there should be a default encoding that Windows uses that I can then "decode" with Ruby using CSV.parse.

Comment: Microsoft software tends to use encoding 'UTF-16LE'.